# Cannot remove Jquery inserted div using a nested button

Tags: jquery

I have some jquery code inserting a div like this

```
function popUpBox(){
$(".openBox").click(function(){     
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#"+id).append('<div class="box1"><div class="button1">Submit</div></div>');
    closeBox();
});
}

function closeBox(){
     $(".button1").click(function(){
          $(".box1").remove();
     });
}
```

The function popUpBox is called on document.ready. And of course I have a div like this...

```
<div class="openBox" id="id1">Open Box</div>
```

The closeBox() function does not seem bind the remove() event to the button. I have tried to use a bind and parent.remove but to no avail.

Comment: Instead of `var id = $(this).attr('id'); $("#"+id).append(...);` you can just write `$(this).append(...);`.

Comment: Your code snippet is missing a closing `'` char on line 4

Comment: Yes, thank you. I did that because I may need to expand the function and use the id somewhere else, but you are correct.

Comment: Copying error. Corrected. Thanks. Problem remains.

Comment: try using .live() to bind the dynamically added events

Comment: It's a little more concise to use `var id = this.id;` as you avoid having to convert to a jQuery object and *then* access the `id` via the `.attr()` method. Albeit it's only a micro-micro-optimisation...@tmjam: `live()` is deprecated as of version 1.7. Earlier jQuery versions should use `delegate()` instead, and 1.7+ should use `on()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works. The problem is that the click on the `Submit` buttons also triggers the parent event handler. So you are removing the popup box, but immediately adding one again.

Prevent triggering the parent event handler by [stopping the event from bubbling up](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/):

```
function closeBox(){
     $(".button1").click(function(e){
          e.stopPropagation();
          $(".box1").remove();
     });
}
```

[quirksmode.org has a great article about this](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html).

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5arns/1/)

That said, instead of binding the event handler every time again, you can bind it once and use *event delegation*:

```
function popUpBox(){
    $(".openBox").click(function(){     
        $(this).append('<div class="box1"><div class="button1">Submit</div></div>');

    }).on('click', '.button1', function(e) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        $(this).closest('.box1').remove();
    });
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5arns/2/)